# How to Set focus

Tags: tkinter, event-handling, setfocus

The following mini-script works with a keyboard event only AFTER one clicks with the Mouse on the root and/or the frame. Is there a way to start immediately with a keyboard event (i.e. w/o a mouse-click)?

```
from Tkinter import *

def key(event):
    print ("pressed")

root=Tk()
root.focus_set()

frame = Frame(root, bg="pink",width=1000, height=800)
frame.pack()

root.bind("<Key>", key)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think this depends on the platform, and how you start the app. Are you starting the app by double-clicking on its icon? Starting it from the command line? Starting from an editor? What platform are you running on?

Comment: in Windows; starting from "Run" in  Pyscripter or IDLE .